# Very Simple Redirect for Tablet

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a very simple HTML site and need to re-direct to a separate URL for Tablet and Mobile. I have the Mobile working with the following. Is there something I can add that is not too complex so it works for tablets as well?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "https://www.londonontariomortgages.ca/m/index.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: How is a "tablet" different from a "laptop"? (Hint: it isn't.)

Comment: You really should consider responsive design. Separate mobile sites are a severe pain to maintain and often a shitty experience for the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use `navigator.userAgent` and `Regex` to check user device

```js
function Init(){
    if( /Android|iPhone|iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
     //mobile device
        document.location = "https://www.londonontariomortgages.ca/m/index.html";
    }else {
     
        document.location = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50994561/very-simple-redirect-for-tablet/50994679?noredirect=1#";
    }
}
Init();
```

Comment: I am sorry - I am really bad at this - Do I just copy and paste that into the head section of my index.html?

Comment: @MarkMitchell I add full code you can paste into your script tag.

Comment: I think I did :)

Answer (score 1):

Nowdays you dont check for specific devices. Why? Because ther are too many to keep track of.

Thats why you check for **features** to act accordingly.

[modernizr](https://modernizr.com/)

You can make your Website **responsive** aswell. Take a look at [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).
By using this you configure your site to behave like "put that down there if the screen is medium sized" (they have standard breakpoints to determine if a screen is small medium large etc., which are widely used)

**EDIT**

To actually detect devices-types: [mobile-detect](http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/)

Comment: Thank you - I already have the mobile/tablet site made, as well as my original site - so I just need to re-direct

Comment: @MarkMitchell added link to a device-type detection script

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use `mobiledetect` package.

> composer require mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib

```
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
// any mobile devices
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
  // do something for mobile users
}

// Any tablet device.
if( $detect->isTablet() ){
 // do something for tablet users
}
```